# IE View Source unable to find the dynamic value binded through jQuery Ajax calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

View Source from the IE browser, to check if the values are binded to labels and input boxes whenever the partial view are being loaded dynamically through jQuery ajax call.
How to find the updated values to text boxes and labels?

I know by using Firebug or web-kit or chrome inspect element we can identify but through view source how can this be achieved>?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that through IE View Source, in IE8 you have Developer Tools for this (Shortcut: F12)

Comment: Through an Ajax call i update or load the value to DIV in the existing page. So, why cant i view the values in view source?

Comment: View source will show you the page source as IE receives it when the page first loads. Whatever you update on the DOM later (thorugh ajax or other) won't be shown in the Page Source.

Answer (score 0):

View Source will show you the actual static markup sent from the webserver.
It doesn't show dynamic updates.